# Calculating the difference between max of even numbers and min of odd numbers of an array

Tags: java, arrays

The question statement says -
**You are given an array of integers A of size N. Return the difference between the maximum among all even numbers of A and the minimum among all odd numbers in A.**

Examples - A = [5, 17, 100, 1] - Ans => 100-1 = 99

My Approach -

```
public class Solution {
    public int solve(int[] A) {
        int n = A.length;
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
            int max1 = A[i];
            if(max1%2 == 0) {
                max = max1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            int min1 = A[i];
            if(min1%2 == 1) {
                min = min1;
                break;
            }
        }
        int d = max-min;
        return d;
    }
}
```

The code is working fine for all input values other than negatives and I don't know why?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you output intermediate values and compare it for expected values for some test values? The definition of "even" for negative numbers might be different than your undestanding and/or the effect of the `%` operator.

Comment: I miss the part of your code where you keep track of maximum and minimum. Something like "if larger than max yet" and "if lower than min yet".

Comment: If were looking for max and min among potentially negative numbers, the inits of 0 for both min and max are doubtful.

Comment: "The code is working fine for all input values other than negatives". Can you give more examples for which it does work?

Comment: Why are you sorting the array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write code like this. I change a little your code.

```
public int solve(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(arr[i]>max && arr[i]%2==0) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(arr[i]<min && arr[i]%2!=0) {
            min= arr[i];
        }
    }
    int d = max-min;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: This code is working only for negatives. When I tried this for positive values, it just returned 0 as the minimum odd value but the max value is still coming fine.

Comment: No I run this code is working negative and positive numbers

Comment: @ElvinAliyev if you have only positive numbers, then min will always be 0

Comment: Il works whenever even numbers are positive and odd numbers are negative.

Answer (score 0):

My Approach ->

```
public int solve(int[] A) {

    int maxEven=-1,minOdd=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        if(A[i]%2==0)
        {
            if(maxEven==-1)
                maxEven=A[i];
            else{
                if(A[i]>maxEven)
                    maxEven=A[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(minOdd==-1)
                minOdd=A[i];
            else
            {
                if(A[i]<minOdd)
                    minOdd=A[i];
            }
        }

    }

    return maxEven-minOdd;
}
```

Comment: You just have to hope that `A` doesn't contain `-1`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public int solve(int[] A) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int a: A) {
        if(a%2 == 0) {
            if (a > max) {
               max = a;
            }
        } else {
            if (a < min) {
               min = a;
            }
        }
    }
    int d = max-min;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: What will be if there is no evens in a array? (but many odd numbers)

Comment: @YadabSd something very small

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void solve(int[] A) {
        
    int n = A.length;
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
        int max1 = A[i];
        if(max1%2 == 0) {
            max = max1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int min1 = A[i];
        if(min1%2 == 1 || min1%2 == -1) {
            min = min1;
            break;
        }
    }
    int d = max-min;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int dif(int[] A) {
    int max = A[0];
    int min = A[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] > max && A[i] % 2 == 0) {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] < min && A[i] % 2 != 0) {
            min = A[i];
        }
    }
    int result = max - min;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

U have initialized min with 0 in the beginning. It will always be the min value if you entr all positive numbrs

Comment: please take the time to write real English words (not _u_, f.i.) and don't forget to write them completely (fill up the missing letters :)